# I want the players score to be assigned to the dictionary to current player, instead it is creating a new instance, please ask if you have questions

Tags: python, tkinter

This is a wheel of fortune game, everything works expect the player's scores. I have made a dictionary that stores 3 players. When the player guesses a correct letter in the phrases I would want it to assign the score to the players place in the dictionary.
For example
It is players 1 turn and they guess 1 letter right and the wheel is at 300 point
What I want it to do is to say {'Player1': 300,'Player2': 0,'Player3': 0}
instead it does {'Player1': 300,'Player2': 0,'Player3': 0, 0:300}

```
from tkinter import *
import random

phrase_list = []
phrases_text = open("phrases.txt").read().splitlines()
for phrase in phrases_text:
    phrase_list.append(phrase)
    phrase = random.choice(phrase_list)
guessed = []
players_score = {}
players = []
current_player = 0
prizes = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600]
prize = random.choice(prizes)


guessed.clear()

def incorrect():
    global current_player
    current_player += 1


def player_assign():
    for i in range (1, 4):
        p_name = "Player" + str(i)
        players.append(p_name)
        players_score[p_name] = 0
        text99.set(players_score)


def player_rotate():
    global current_player
    text5.set("The turn for " + players[current_player])
    if current_player >= len(players):
        current_player = 0





def check_phrase():
    global current_player
    text5.set("Its " + players[current_player] + "s turn")
    if current_player >= len(players):
        current_player = 0

    place_holder = ""
    
    guess = str(entry_window.get()).lower()
    def points():
        prize_assign = phrase.count(guess) * prize
        players_score[current_player] = prize_assign
        text88.set(prize)
        text99.set(players_score)

        
    if guess == phrase:
        text.set("Good job you guessed the phrase, it was " + phrase) 
    elif guess in guessed:
        text.set("You already guessed that letter")
        entry_window.delete(0, END) 

    elif len(guess) > 1:
        text.set("Sorry that was not the phrase")
        entry_window.delete(0, END)
        text5.set("The turn for " + players[current_player])

    elif guess in phrase:
        text.set("Good job, the letter " + str(guess) + " is in the word")
        guessed.append(guess)
        points()
        entry_window.delete(0, END)

    elif guess.isalpha() is False:
        text.set("Please do not enter special characters or numbers")
        entry_window.delete(0, END)

    else:
        text.set("No, the letter " + str(guess) + " is not in the word")
        guessed.append(guess)
        entry_window.delete(0, END)
        incorrect()
    for char in phrase:
        if char == " ":
            place_holder = place_holder + " "
        elif char in guessed:
            place_holder = place_holder + char
            text2.set(place_holder)
        else:
            place_holder = place_holder + "_ "
            text2.set(place_holder)
    i = ",".join(guessed)
    text3.set("Letters guessed: " + i)


# Main GUI
root = Tk()
root.title("Wheel of Fortune")
root.geometry("500x300")

# Label to instruct the user on what to do.
label = Label(root, text="Welcome to weel of Fortune \n"
                "Guess a letter in the phrase, or guess the "
                "whole phrase")
label.pack()

text5 = StringVar()
text5.set("Its Player 1s turn")
player_rotation = Label(root,  textvariable=text5)
player_rotation.pack()

# User input box
entry_window = Entry(root, width=40, borderwidth=5)
entry_window.pack()

# Check button to check the phrase
button_check = Button(root, text="Check", command=check_phrase)
button_check.pack()

# Creating a text variable which changes depending on the users input
text = StringVar()
text.set("")
feedback_text = Label(root,  textvariable=text)
feedback_text.pack()

# Creating a text variable which prints the letters placeholders/underscores
text2 = StringVar()
text2.set("_ "*len(phrase))
place_holders = Label(root,  textvariable=text2)
place_holders.pack()

# Creating a text variable which show the guessed letters
text3 = StringVar()
text3.set("Letters guessed: ")
place_holders = Label(root,  textvariable=text3)
place_holders.pack()

# Creating a text variable which shows the players and the points
text99 = StringVar()
text99.set(" iii")
score = Label(root,  textvariable=text99)
score.pack()

text88 = StringVar()
text88.set(" eee")
wheel = Label(root,  textvariable=text88)
wheel.pack()

place_holders.pack()
player_assign()


# Exit button to exit the program
button_exit = Button(root, text="Exit", command=root.destroy)
button_exit.pack()

# Main loop for the whole GUI
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a small oversight in the points function within check_phrase:

```
from tkinter import *
import random

phrase_list = []
# phrases_text = open("phrases.txt").read().splitlines()
phrases_text = ["I am bob", "I am retarded"]
for phrase in phrases_text:
    phrase_list.append(phrase)
    phrase = random.choice(phrase_list)
guessed = []
players_score = {}
players = []
current_player = 0
prizes = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600]
prize = random.choice(prizes)


guessed.clear()


def incorrect():
    global current_player
    current_player += 1


def player_assign():
    for i in range(1, 4):
        p_name = "Player" + str(i)
        players.append(p_name)
        players_score[p_name] = 0
        text99.set(players_score)


def player_rotate():
    global current_player
    text5.set("The turn for " + players[current_player])
    if current_player >= len(players):
        current_player = 0


def check_phrase():
    global current_player
    text5.set("Its " + players[current_player] + "s turn")
    if current_player >= len(players):
        current_player = 0

    place_holder = ""

    guess = str(entry_window.get()).lower()

    def points():
        prize_assign = phrase.count(guess) * prize
        players_score[players[current_player]] += prize_assign
        text88.set(prize)
        text99.set(players_score)

    if guess == phrase:
        text.set("Good job you guessed the phrase, it was " + phrase)
    elif guess in guessed:
        text.set("You already guessed that letter")
        entry_window.delete(0, END)

    elif len(guess) > 1:
        text.set("Sorry that was not the phrase")
        entry_window.delete(0, END)
        text5.set("The turn for " + players[current_player])

    elif guess in phrase:
        text.set("Good job, the letter " + str(guess) + " is in the word")
        guessed.append(guess)
        points()
        entry_window.delete(0, END)

    elif guess.isalpha() is False:
        text.set("Please do not enter special characters or numbers")
        entry_window.delete(0, END)

    else:
        text.set("No, the letter " + str(guess) + " is not in the word")
        guessed.append(guess)
        entry_window.delete(0, END)
        incorrect()
    for char in phrase:
        if char == " ":
            place_holder = place_holder + " "
        elif char in guessed:
            place_holder = place_holder + char
            text2.set(place_holder)
        else:
            place_holder = place_holder + "_ "
            text2.set(place_holder)
    i = ",".join(guessed)
    text3.set("Letters guessed: " + i)


# Main GUI
root = Tk()
root.title("Wheel of Fortune")
root.geometry("500x300")

# Label to instruct the user on what to do.
label = Label(root, text="Welcome to weel of Fortune \n"
              "Guess a letter in the phrase, or guess the "
              "whole phrase")
label.pack()

text5 = StringVar()
text5.set("Its Player 1s turn")
player_rotation = Label(root,  textvariable=text5)
player_rotation.pack()

# User input box
entry_window = Entry(root, width=40, borderwidth=5)
entry_window.pack()

# Check button to check the phrase
button_check = Button(root, text="Check", command=check_phrase)
button_check.pack()

# Creating a text variable which changes depending on the users input
text = StringVar()
text.set("")
feedback_text = Label(root,  textvariable=text)
feedback_text.pack()

# Creating a text variable which prints the letters placeholders/underscores
text2 = StringVar()
text2.set("_ "*len(phrase))
place_holders = Label(root,  textvariable=text2)
place_holders.pack()

# Creating a text variable which show the guessed letters
text3 = StringVar()
text3.set("Letters guessed: ")
place_holders = Label(root,  textvariable=text3)
place_holders.pack()

# Creating a text variable which shows the players and the points
text99 = StringVar()
text99.set(" iii")
score = Label(root,  textvariable=text99)
score.pack()

text88 = StringVar()
text88.set(" eee")
wheel = Label(root,  textvariable=text88)
wheel.pack()

place_holders.pack()
player_assign()


# Exit button to exit the program
button_exit = Button(root, text="Exit", command=root.destroy)
button_exit.pack()

# Main loop for the whole GUI
root.mainloop()
```

Should now work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the `points()` method. `current_player` is an integer and you use it as the key for the `players_score` dictionary. `players[current_player]` should be the dictionary key.

```
def points():
    prize_assign = phrase.count(guess) * prize
    players_score[players[current_player]] = prize_assign
    text88.set(prize)
    text99.set(players_score)
```